# Facebook Graph API /group-id/photos doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Graph API /group-id/photos doesn't work.

I am the group Administrator and my access_token has user_managed_groups permission.

When I try to get the list of photos published in the group, there is none.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What API version are you using? [`/group/photos` has been removed with v2.6](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/group/photos), so building new functionality based on it is not the best idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using version 2.5  Can I use an earlier one?

Comment: Only if you have an app that was created before v2.6 was announced.

Comment: What permissions are present in the access token you're using? (assuming it's <v2.6)